# How to validate that a specific ammount of checkboxes are checked in PHP

Tags: php, validation, checkbox

I have to validate that maximum 3 checkboxes are clicked. There are 11. How could I do this efficiently and without testing every possible situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
if (count($_POST['checkbox_name']) === 3)
{
  // your code here.....
}
```

where your checkbox names should be suffixed with `[]` eg:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name[]" value="3" />
```